# i3wm multi-monitor error while moving displays

Tags: fedora, nvidia, window-manager, i3, tiling-wm

I am trying out i3wm with 2 displays and when I logged in for the first time my displays were swapped around. This doesn't happen with Gnome 3. So I used arandr (GUI tool that generates xrandr commands) to swap my displays so that I can move my mouse across the screen as normal. When I save the change it swaps the monitors and allows me to move my mouse across the 2 displays but the click areas are the opposite.

Eg: If I have chrome on the left display, it would only register click events around the same area on the right side.

Below is a screenshot of how my displays look when I login for the first time (DVI-D-1 should be left and DVI-I-1 should be right).[image]

Below is the xrandr command I run to swap my displays

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DVI-D-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --off
```

Here is the output of the GPU

```
lspci | grep VGA 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick answer**

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --output DVI-D-1 --auto --left-of DVI-I-1
```

---

**Detailed Answer**

I got help from the i3 IRC chat room and they explained that my previous command shown below only **'corrected'** a not present offset. Therefore,  I needed to switch the devices **'logically'** in order to fully implement my swap. Because my devices already had the correct resolutions set, I just used the `--left-of` option but you may need to set the `--mode` and any other options. Your Mileage May Vary.

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --off --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DVI-D-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --off
```